# Can't inset Radio Button Value in table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple Feedback form where the user can select only one value which is

Good Better Best Excellent

These are fixed text and values so I am hard coding it.Have tried these ways to get their values, none of the attempt is working.

How do I saved the selected radio buttons value in table and how do I retain it on Editing?

Feedback is a column of datatype int in my table and model.

In all the cases 0 is saved on any selection and attempt 2 is wrong as only one radio button is displayed.

Attempt 1

```
        @Html.Label("Good")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FeedBack, false)

        @Html.Label("Better")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FeedBack, false)

        @Html.Label("Best")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FeedBack, false)

        @Html.Label("Excellent")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FeedBack, false)
```

Attempt 2

```
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FeedBack,
        new List<SelectListItem>{new SelectListItem{Text="Good",Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Better", Value = "2" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Best", Value = "3" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Excellent",Value="4" } })
```

Attempt 3

```
        @Html.RadioButton("rb", 1, isChecked: false)@Html.Label("Good")
        @Html.RadioButton("rb", 2, isChecked: false)@Html.Label("Better")
        @Html.RadioButton("rb", 3, isChecked: false)@Html.Label("Best")
        @Html.RadioButton("rb", 4, isChecked: false)@Html.Label("Excellent")
```

Comment: Where is the code for saving data ? The action method which handles the form submission ?

Comment: Thanks for helping was using auto generated code using Entity Framework for Inserting and updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given all your radio buttons a value of `false` which cannot be bound to a property which is typeof `int`. Assuming your values are `1` (Good) to `4`(Excellent), then your view needs to be

```
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FeedBack, 1, new { id = "" })
    <span>Good</span>
</label>
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FeedBack, 2, new { id = "" })
    <span>Better</span>
</label>
.... // ditto for Better (value=3) and Excellent(value=4)
```

Side note: `@Html.Label("Good")` create a label element associated with a form control named `Good` which does not exist, so clicking on it would not check/uncheck the associated button.

I also recommend you consider using an `enum` for your values, rather than `int`. And might want to consider how 'Excellect' can be rated higher that 'Best'

Comment: It works fine both on insert and update. Importance of  @Html.Label("Good") also understood.                                                     But what is the use of the third parameter new {id=""}

Comment: Because otherwise it will be generating all the radio buttons with `id="FeedBack"` and duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html. The `new { id = "" }` removes it. Unless your using javascript to access a specific button then the `id` attribute is not really required.

Comment: And alternative would be to use `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FeedBack, 1, new { id = "good" })` (i.e give each one a unique `id`) and `@Html.LabelFor("Good")` or `<label for="good">Good</label>`

Comment: Knowledgable                                                                                               Understood.